# Scroll to content when hidden div is visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not very great with this and I can't figure this out. I have three buttons and three hidden divs. When a button is clicked, the hidden content is revealed. How can I make the page scroll down so that the beginning of the content is at the top of the page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(num) {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('div1').style.height='0px';
    document.getElementById('div1').style.overflow='hidden';
    document.getElementById('div2').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('div2').style.height='0px';
    document.getElementById('div2').style.overflow='hidden';
    document.getElementById('div3').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('div3').style.height='0px';
    document.getElementById('div3').style.overflow='hidden';
    document.getElementById('div'+num).style.visibility='visible';
    document.getElementById('div'+num).style.height='10px';
    document.getElementById('div'+num).style.overflow='visible';    
}
</script>
```

My Css:

```
#div1, #div2, #div3 {
    visibility: hidden;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden

}

.button {
    background-color: green;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

My buttons:

```
<input type="button" class="button" name="Showdiv1" value="Show Div 1" onclick="showDiv('1')" />
<input type="button" class="button" name="Showdiv2" value="Show Div 2" onclick="showDiv('2')" />
<input type="button" class="button" name="Showdiv3" value="Show Div 3" onclick="showDiv('3')" />
<div id="div1"> I'm div1 </div>
<div id="div2"> I'm div2 </div>
<div id="div3"> <form style="margin-top:1000px;height: 1000px;" id="form1">
        Form with huge data in it
        </form> </div>
```

A demo where div 3 has a long form that starts further down the page: https://jsfiddle.net/cgrouge/Lx0pyg4L/

Comment: If you were using JQuery I would suggest using something like: Get the top margin of the selected content (First off, use a `selected` class, rather than all those JS style changes) and scroll to that position on the page (`$('html, body').scrollTop(selected items top margin)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
 $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
});
});
```

Edit 1:

[Reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)
You can use this script. It works perfectly for your purpose. You will need to put your input tags inside a anchor tag.

Edit 2:

[Pen](http://codepen.io/ph110293/pen/MewJdx)

Comment: So would I include the href link on my button and if so, will that still reveal my hidden divs on click?

Comment: I have added a codepen link in the answer. You can check that. Click on div3 and you should be able to see your desired effect. Even if you add anchor tags, It won't reveal your divs unless you click

Comment: That works great, thank you! Could I slow the animation down so you can see the page scroll rather than jumping to the div3 content?

Comment: I am trying to figure that out. Some existing code must be interfering with it

Comment: I just needed to link the JQuery library, that's all. https://jsfiddle.net/cgrouge/38rq45jp/ Thank you so much for your help!!!